# Android Download And Install Non-Marketplace App

Tags: android, installation

Android 2.1  Downloaded APK from server.  Now I want to programaticllly install this on the phone/tablet without starting it up.  Just install it.  How do I do this on Android 2.1?

Comment: what permissions do i need and what api calls do I make to register the app for deployment?

Comment: what do you mean without starting up??

Comment: anyway what is the best way to just install it.

Comment: If you have a file manager you can click on the APK, and you should be able to install it (one such filemanager is: astro). 
Or if you're plugged in via usb you can use adb to install it with 'adb install filename.apk'

Comment: to clarify I am looking for one app an admin app to install the second app after download.

Answer (score 1):

Installing an app doesnt necessarily cause the app to start running, unless the app is meant to run as a service, in which case I dont know of any way to install the app and prevent it from hooking into your system and running behind the scenes.

As far as programatic installatation, a quick google search turned this up as the successor to PackageManager.installPackage:
http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/android-developers@googlegroups.com/2010-01/msg03943.html

Comment: I don't know the answer to this one, but it must be possible cos third party app stores manage it. So I guess you would need an app to install other apps (if that makes sense). Where the first app can use the correct permissions etc to be able to install an app for the user.

Comment: well notice that this approach uses startActivity ...  Why the startActivity?

Comment: Yes this is an approach to install the app.  But notice the startActivity(intent).  I would like to determine if this is correct or only way to programatically install a third party app not from market place

Comment: I guess I don't understand the objection to startActivity(). What is it about startActivity you dont like?  I suspect that part of the reason its now done this way is user security.

Comment: well what does startActivity have to do with installation?

Comment: To me startActivity means just that.  You start an page of an already installed app. It really has nothing to do with installation per se.

Comment: I think what this is doing is calling the System installer.

Comment: I -believe- it means an installation prompt activity starts with a dialog asking the user to decide whether or not they want to allow the app to be installed.  It makes sense if you think about it since every app has its own permission scheme as far as what phone resources it wants/needs to use and its up to the user to decide whether or not they trust the app with those resources.

Comment: Imagine trying to install an app that requires more permissions than the app making the install request has.  If that installation was allowed to go on unchecked the android os would have to do one of two things: 1 - allow the new app to install with permission granted to all needed services which is a *big* security hole.  Or 2 - it could let the app install but force the app to crash whenever it was run because the permissions werent there to successfully run.

Comment: In the same way, you cannot programatically enable GPS...all you can do is popup a window for the user to enable gps themselves.  Same thing.

Comment: So what you are doing here is running the System Installer with the startActivity.  I guess thats ok, but its exactly the same as doing an actual install.  I would use this if I could somehow stay in my calling app while doing this or return to it.  I just don't want to go outside the calling app and come up in an entirely new context

Comment: So this is almost what I need, but is there a way to stay in my admin app while calling the System Installer or Return to my admin app after the system installer completes?

Comment: I am going to post that as a separate question

Comment: you should automatically return to your app from the installer activity regardless of whether or not the user accepts or declines the install.  Unfortutantely I think its a necessity that the install activity runs as its own activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254174/running-android-system-apps-from-custom-admin-app

Comment: as mentioned above, the answer to the second part of your newly posted question is that your app will automatically regain focus after the user finishes with the install activity.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the app, download the Android SDK and adb, enable USB debugging, connect the device to your machine via a USB cable and do an adb install of the APK.  If you're using Windows to deploy the app, you'll have to download the USB drivers as well.  My recommendation is to use either Linux or a Mac for easier deployment.

From the command line, you'll do something like this:

```
$ adb install yourdownloadedpackage.apk
```

If you've connected your device appropriately you should see your application if the install completed successfully.

Comment: I should have clarified.  I am looking one app already on the phone to install the app.