# Running Android System Apps from Custom Admin App

Tags: android

I am writing an Admin App that will download the latest updated app from my website and install.  The only way to do the install that I have found is to invoke the package installer using a starActivity().  Passing control over to the System Installer app makes perfect sense, but it also interferes with the user experience of the admin app.  How can I keep the user inside my admin app while interacting with the System Installer app?  Or at least return to my Admin app after they exit the System Installer app?  This question really applies anytime you need to pop up a system app to do something.  How do you preserve the user experience of the app that launches the system app?

Comment: what happens now when they press back out of the installer app?

Comment: I coded this a while ago.  I will be reaching this point in code again.  I know the user experience was not good. But I'll update this later when I reach that point, and describe exactly what it does. Thanks

Comment: This is a very important question as any admin app/activity will likely need to invoke an system app to handle part of the admin functions.

Comment: What I want to find is the best way to preserve the user experience when invoking system apps from custom android admin app or activity page.  I want the most user friendly way to invoke the system installer from another app. Thanks

Comment: There is a edit button that you can use to add more info to your question.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot install applications without the system installer, it would be a serious security risk - you could bypass showing the list of required permissions. (On rooted devices, it is possible via filesystem operations).

Users can return to your application via the back key after install (see [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) about task and activity stacks). If I remember correctly, closing the installer with the "Done" button will also have the same result, try it with Astro).